# How to replace a digit by a letter?

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace, characters, numbers

I want to replace some digits by letters such that

```
1 ---> a
2 ---> b
...
```

In emacs I have tried the following replacement:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET \([0-9]+\) RET \,(string (+ ?a \#1)) RET
```

It works, but in replacement I obtain `1 --> b`, `2 --> c`, and so on. Please, how can I fix it?

PS: I know that with my code `26 --> {`, but it is not a problem because my digits are generally less than 26.

Comment: Does (+ (1- ?a) \#1) work?

Comment: @InHarmsWay Yes, it works! Thanks!

Comment: @InHarmsWay: Please post your comment as an answer. OP: Please accept the answer. Alternatively, if you think your question and the answer aren't helpful for other readers then please consider deleting the question. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
M-x query-replace-regexp RET \([0-9]+\) RET \,(string (+ (1- ?a) \#1)) RET
```